# Spring LDAP - Remove user from group

Tags: spring-ldap

I want to know what's the best way to remove a user from a group (without removing the user itself) using Spring LDAP 1.3.1. (The Spring LDAP version is important here because I can't upgrade right now and I'm NOT using the ODM).

I've tried this, but it doesn't work. The memberOf attribute is removed for the user, but the user entry remains in the group.

```
public void disable(User user) {
    Name dn = buildDn(user.getUsername());

    Attribute attr = new BasicAttribute("memberOf");
    ModificationItem item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, attr);

    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[] { item });
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove user from group you have to also delete him from members attribute of this group.